# How to get directory of where scene is stored?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a scene called `Character1` ( res://Scenes/Characters/Character1.tscn )
and it is instanced in another scene `Level1` ( res://Scenes/Levels/Level1.tscn )

and I need to get the directory of the scene of Character1

I tried this inside the script of Character1:
`print(get_tree().edited_scene_root.filename.get_base_dir())`

But this prints

> res://Scenes/Levels

Whereas I need it to print

> res://Scenes/Characters

Answer (score 1):

Just for safty:
filename is only set for the topmost node of an scene. See [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/de/stable/classes/class_node.html?highlight=filename#class-node-property-filename)

Otherwise it is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution but I'm not sure if it will work in every situation:

```
if(filename==""):
    print(get_tree().edited_scene_root.filename.get_base_dir())
else:
    print(filename.get_base_dir())
```